# Python: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'\x00

Tags: python-3.x, client-server, diffie-hellman

I am making a client-server program implementing the Diffie-Hellman algorithm

Client:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import math
import socket

host = "localhost"
port = 1200
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,   socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

print("Connected with Server")

sharedPrime = 23    # p
sharedBase = 5      # g

aliceSecret = 6     # a

s.send(bytes(aliceSecret))
bobSecret=s.recv(1024)

# Alice Sends Bob A = g^a mod p
A = (sharedBase**aliceSecret) % sharedPrime

s.send(bytes(A))
B=s.recv(1024)

B=B.decode()
# Alice Computes Shared Secret: s = B^a mod p
aliceSharedSecret = (int(B)** aliceSecret) % sharedPrime
print( "Alice Shared Secret: ", aliceSharedSecret )
```

The server code is basically the same, except it handles "Bob's" side of the algorithm. My problem starts at this line:

```
aliceSharedSecret = (int(B)** aliceSecret) % sharedPrime
```

Which gives me this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I've gone back to see what "B" actually is and it's just blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to have stopped the error, but what does this line mean?

Answer (score 3):

Look at this line:

```
s.send(bytes(aliceSecret))
```

You convert `int` value to `bytes` here. This produces result like `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` that later cannot be directly casted to `int` even after decoding because it's not number in decimal form. There are 2 possible solutions:

1) Properly decode value, this line will interpret `bytes` object as `int` splitted into bytes:

```
B = int.from_bytes(B, byteorder='big', signed=False)  # instead of B = B.decode()
```

2) Convert your original `int` value to `str` before converting to `bytes` so back convertation will work

Answer (score 0):

Clean after decoding

```
B=B.decode().strip('\x00')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).